# Show all children per parent

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Tables.

T1:questions

- question_ID
- is_active
- question
- timestamp

T2:answers

- answerID
- answer
- questionid

I want to make a query that shows:

```
question 1
answer 1
answer 2
answer 3

question 2
answer 1
answer 2

question 3
answer 1
answer 2
answer 3
answer 4
```

Some people state I need an array, others say I need recursive queries.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please read [this post](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) on how to ask for query writing help.

Comment: i would like to apologize not posting universal code. First timer!

Comment: Can you give me a little push in the right direction? I am trying to see it in php, but i dont see the trees around the forest anymore...

Comment: Use solution suggested by Rick James, and do what remains in the application

Answer (score 0):

That format is not practical to generate using SQL.  The *information* is easy to fetch:

```
SELECT question, answer FROM Questions JOIN Answers ON ... ORDER BY ...
```

but that gives you

```
question1  ans1
question1  ans2
question1  ans3
question2  ans1
question2  ans2
question2  ans3
question2  ans4
question3  ans1
...
```